# Launch rstudio-server from terminal linux

Tags: r, linux, rstudio-server

I'm an Ubuntu user and I used to work with the standard version of Rstudio on my computer. After reading about the [server version](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552306-Getting-Started) I installed it on my PC and I'm working with it now. Although I'm very happy with rstudio-server version, I have been facing some difficulties to keep with some old practices. Particularly, I use to launch, open and create new files from the terminal using `rstudio` keyword - I'm specially fond to the possibility of open files in current rstudio session through the terminal window within rstudio. However, I cannot figure out which command is equivalent in rstudio-server.

I tried, without success, the following commands:

```
rstudio-server
```

and

```
r-server
```

Interestingly, when I type `which rstudio` (to find the path of the program's binary files), the terminal did not return any results. The program is installed and working normally, but I just can't find it on my PC

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Cant you use: sudo su - -c "R -e \"file.edit('test.R')"" on the server, for exampe?

Comment: Or probably this helps: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-server-terminal/12130

Comment: And here is also some unformation about the IDE and Server terminal differences https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115010737148-Using-the-RStudio-Terminal?mobile_site=true

Comment: thank you @ava for your useful comments. I will use your recommendations and other sources to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Run `rstudio-server start`, then open a new tab on your preferred browser and type *localhost:8787*

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo rstudio-server start`, open a browser, and type `http://localhost:8787`. That should do